# How to perform a t.test for multiple groups of variables

Tags: r

I'm working with `anorexia` table in R. I need to compare Prewt-values with `t.test` for each Treat-group.

The comparison should be between Cont and CBT, Cont and FT and CBT and FT groups, so 3 `t.test`. Is there any short way to do this, without extracting the groups of "Treat" first?

UPD: I'm currently using `t.test(anorexia$Prewt[anorexia$Treat == 'CBT'], anorexia$Prewt[anorexia$Treat == 'FT'])`, and it works fine! Any neater solutions are welcome, though.

Answer (score 1):

Using `combn` and `for` loop we could easily iterate through all combinations:

```r
t.tests <- function(x, g) {
grs <- combn(unique(g), 2, simplify = FALSE)

results <- list()

for(i in seq_len(length(grs))) {
  gg <- grs[[i]]
  results[[i]] <- t.test(x[g == gg[1]], 
                         x[g == gg[2]])
}

names(results) <- lapply(grs, function(x) paste0(as.character(x), collapse = "_"))

results
}

library(MASS)
data(anorexia)

results <- t.tests(anorexia$Prewt, anorexia$Treat)
 
results$CBT_FT
# equalt to your code
t.test(anorexia$Prewt[anorexia$Treat == 'CBT'], anorexia$Prewt[anorexia$Treat == 'FT'])
```